# API not being called from Web

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm trying to call some data from an API to build a basic weather app as practice.

I'm using the inspect element on my chrome browser to see if the console will display my data in the log but to no avail.

I've hit a block on this and i feel like i'm simply missing some code or doing something small wrong.
Any help would be appreciated.

The code below is from my weather.ts provider

```
constructor(public http: HttpClient)
  {
    console.log('Hello WeatherProvider Provider');
    //this.url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=dublin,Ireland&APPID=b90245073a8392aec69a261861286c3b';

  }

  // getting weather info from API with a custom city and country
  getWeather(city, country):Observable<any> 
  {
    return this.http.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city+','+country+'&APPID='+this.apiKey);
  }

}
```

The console.log in the constructor appears in the console but nothing further.

The code 
below is from my home.ts page

```
export class HomePage
{
  weather: any;
  location: 
  {
    city: string,
    country: string
  }

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private weatherProvider:WeatherProvider) 
  {

  }

  ionWillEnter()
  {
    this.location = {city: 'dublin', country: 'Ireland'}

    this.weatherProvider.getWeather(this.location.city, this.location.country).subscribe(weather => {
      console.log(weather);
    });
  }

}
```

The console.log(weather); is my ultimate end goal. To have it appear in the console as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mispelled the lifecycle method name.

You probably want to use either `ionViewWillEnter` or `ngOnInit`

Answer (score 0):

Angular has life cycle methods. 
NgonInit will be called initially, so you need to put ur code in onInit method.
Refer to other life cycle hooks here
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks